# How to compare arrays and find number of matches sorted in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, csv, compare

I have a CSV file with about  20000 lines of data.
I need to compare/find out exactly how many times eacy array is repeating it self with the results sorted from highest to lowest.

Example

```
a[0000001] = [23.2 ,54 ,87.9 ,34 ,8]
a[0000002] = [3.2 ,4.9 ,8.7 ,54.3 ,98]
a[0000003] = [2.32 ,24 ,37.9 ,32 ,8.7]
a[0000004] = [22.2 ,54 ,72.1 ,3.4 ,8.8]
```

and so on so forth

I am trying to find exactly how many times each array lets say for example a[0000001] = [23.2 ,54 ,87.9 ,34 ,8] has repeated itself throughout the data.
Arrays needs to sorted from high to low and number of matches also needed to be sorted high to low.

If i psuedocode to describe what is needed

```
a1 = [1,2] 
a2 = [1,4] 
a3 = [1,5] 
a4 = [1,2] 
a5 = [1,4] 
a6 = [1,4] ...........
a20000[1,8] 
for each a# (a1 for example) 
compare a# with a.all 
a1occuredindata = 2 
go to next a# (a2 for example) 
compare a# with a.all 
a2occuredindata = 3 ..... until a20000 
in the end 
sort 
a2 occured highest number of time = 3 followed by 
a1 = 2 so on so forth
```

Comment: I don't quite understand; can you please edit the question to clarify?  The question mentions CSV, but then switches to arrays (or, apparently, an array of arrays).  How is the data you show related to the CSV?  Also, when you say "sorted from high to low", can you please explain what makes an array higher than another?  It would be helpful to see both the input data, and the output you expect.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Please disregard mentioning of CSV. I have arrays as given in the example and about 20,000 of them.

Comment: That's better.  The question could still use some improvement, but now I don't think it needs to be put on hold.  Thank you for improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if you are concerned about performance. A simple way would be to use the arrays themselves as Hash keys.

```
results = {}
arr.each do |row|
  results[row] ||= 0
  results[row] += 1
end

# Occurrences in reverse order
p results.values.reverse.sort

# Unique arrays in desc order
p results.sort { |(_,v1),(_,v2)| v2 <=> v1 }.map { |elem| elem[0] }
```

Comment: Not concerned about performance , just would like to get the job done.
basically i just needs each entry i.e
a1 = [23.2 ,54 ,87.9 ,34 ,8] to be matched with all the others in the data to give result how many number times it has reapeated itself
for example a1 = [23.2 ,54 ,87.9 ,34 ,8] is checked against
a1 = [23.2 ,54 ,87.9 ,34 ,8] 
a2 = [2 ,4 ,9 ,2 ,8] 
a3 = [2 ,5 ,7.9 ,4 ,1] 
a4 = [23.2 ,54 ,87.9 ,34 ,8] 

would result like
a1 [23.2 ,54 ,87.9 ,34 ,8] x 2
and the code then do the same for a2 = [2 ,4 ,9 ,2 ,8]  and so on so forth..

Comment: OK the code above won't be super efficient but should do the job.

I've assumed that the arr array is an array of all of your arrays :)

Comment: If i psuedocode to describe what is needed

a1 = [1,2]
a2 = [1,4]
a3 = [1,5]
a4 = [1,2]
a5 = [1,4]
a6 = [1,4]
...........a20000[1,8]

for each a# (a1 for example)
compare a# with a.all 
a1occuredindata = 2
go to next a# (a2 for example)
compare a# with a.all
a2occuredindata = 3
.....
until a20000

in the end sort 
a2 occured highest number of time = 3
followed by a1 = 2
so on so forth



hope it clarifies

Comment: @user2716736 Additional description belongs in the question, not as a comment. Please [edit] your question and clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_by` to partition the data according to your criteria (each array reverse sorted), then `map` each partition to its size to get the count, then finally sort by the size of each partition.

```
a.group_by(&:sort).map { |x, xs| [x.reverse, xs.size] }.sort_by(&:last).reverse
```

Note that I sort each array low to high and reverse them later. It has the same effect.

Comment: Need more help as to how the above code can be used

Comment: In your example you have an array called `a` so you should be able to copy and paste my code to get the exact output you desire.